# Repeating an image horizontally (non-background image)

Tags: html, css

I can't get this image to repeat horizontally. Note it is not a background image.

https://jsfiddle.net/gcetx8kh/

**HTML:**

```
    <img id="rd" src="http://us.cdn3.123rf.com/168nwm/eriksvoboda/eriksvoboda1411/eriksvoboda141100036/33498305-asphalt-road-texture-with-white-and-yellow-stripes.jpg">
```

**CSS:**

```
#rd {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: 300px; 
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: background-repeat: repeat-x; is works with background image only

Comment: Without it being a background image you *can't* repeat it with CSS. You need to make it the background image to a div with the right height and as much width as you need.

Comment: @RoryO'Keeffe Can you post a jsfiddle that works?

Comment: try like this https://jsfiddle.net/gcetx8kh/3/

Comment: you can't  repeat img - you want to use a background image for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, `background-repeat: repeat-x;` will not work with the `img` tag. Therefore, you will need to add a new div and apply the image as a background image.

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gcetx8kh/4/)**

```
<div id="rd"></div>
```

CSS:

```css
#rd {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 300px;
    background: url(http://us.cdn3.123rf.com/168nwm/eriksvoboda/eriksvoboda1411/eriksvoboda141100036/33498305-asphalt-road-texture-with-white-and-yellow-stripes.jpg) center repeat-x;
    background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

Edit: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gcetx8kh/6/)** with fade on both sides:

```css
#rd {   
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 300px;
    background: url(http://us.cdn3.123rf.com/168nwm/eriksvoboda/eriksvoboda1411/eriksvoboda141100036/33498305-asphalt-road-texture-with-white-and-yellow-stripes.jpg) center repeat-x;    
    background-size: auto 100%;    
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
    
#rd:before {
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);      
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)));     
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);      
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);     
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);    
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);     
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to fade the road on both sides?

Comment: @Jeevan: updated my answer with your requirement.. Hope this is what you want

Answer (score 1):

`background-repeat: repeat-x;` will not work with img tag.
Add a new div and apply the image as background image.

Comment: Please provide a code example for your proposed solution.